# Recursive function not recursing

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to transverse a tree-like structure made of a dictionary of dictionaries with the lowest level dictionary containing a list. Here is an example of the structure:

```
Metabolism[currentL0][currentL1][currentL2][node] = [pathway1, pathway2, pathway3]
```

I used this function to create the data structure:

```
Tree = lambda: defaultdict(Tree)
Metabolism = Tree()
```

The code to generate and populate the data structure works. However, I am trying to use a recursive generator to transverse the "tree" and return the top key and all the lists associated with it. The generator function works through the `if isinstance` test. It enters the `if` block prints `hi` and assigns the right value to `key`, however, it then seems to skip the recursive call and prints `bye`. To test this I placed the `print key` statement at the top of the function and set `key` to `recursive` in the recursive call so the `print key` statement should print the word `recursive`, but it doesn't. Here is the generator function:

```
def walk_dict(d,depth=0,key=""):
   print key
   for k,v in d.items():
      if isinstance(v, defaultdict):
         print "hi"
         if depth == 0:
            key = k
         walk_dict(v,depth+1,"recursive")
         print "bye"
      else:
         yield key, v
```

The test `print` statements seem to confirm that the function is not recursing. It prints a blank line followed by the same number of `hi`s and `bye`s as there are top level dictionary keys. Here is an example of the output:

```
<blank line>
hi
bye
hi
bye
hi
bye
hi
bye
hi
bye
hi
bye
```

Finally, here is the code to call the generator function:

```
for x,y in walk_dict(Metabolism):
    pass
```

Comment: Hi Darwin ,  can you also add a line "print depth"  inbetween lines "for k,v in d.items():" and "if isinstance(v, defaultdict):" . I was thinking if the recursive call with "v" as the new dict wasn't getting through the isinstace check. Also ' Im not sure how many keys are present in the given dict "d"  for depth "0"

Comment: @skippy I added the requested code and it prints `0` for the depth six times. There are six keys for depth 0.

Comment: Strange !  can you also check if you can "print v.items()" before passing it to walk_dict(v,depth+1,"recursive") .I'm just curious because consider the  example isinstance ( {}, dict  )-> which returns True in python  even though an empty dict is compared with the python dict class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you made recursive call, you did not yield the result. Replace this line:

```
         walk_dict(v,depth+1,"recursive")
```

with this line:

```
         for item in walk_dict(v,depth+1,"recursive"):
             yield item
```

If you are running Python 3, you can use the `yield from` construct:

```
         yield from item in walk_dict(v,depth+1,"recursive"):
```

## Update

To answer your question, consider this what the following call does:

```
         walk_dict(v,depth+1,"recursive")
```

In the original code, you simply call `walk_dict`, which returns a generator. However, you did not extract any useful lists from that generator and yield back to your caller.

Comment: I see my mistake of not iterating (i.e. calling next()) on the generator to get the next value. However, I don't see why `yield item` is needed. Is it just giving control back the original generator?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrongly for recursive function. In recursive functions, when you directly call - `walk_dict(v,depth+1,"recursive")` - it just returns the generator object and discards (As you are not doing anything with it) - it would not go through the function.

`walk_dict()` is a geneator function, when you just call `walk_dict()` it will only return the generator object (it will not iterate through it) . Lets show an example of that -

```
>>> def func():
...     print("Hello")
...     yield 10
...
>>>
>>> func()
<generator object func at 0x006FF418>
>>> next(func())
Hello
10
```

As you can see just calling the generator function does nothing, only when you iterate through it (or call next()) you actually call the generator function.

This is what you need to do in your code as well, you need to iterate through `walk_dict()` recursively and yield the results at each level.

Example -

```
def walk_dict(d,depth=0,key=""):
   print key
   for k,v in d.items():
      if isinstance(v, defaultdict):
         print "hi"
         if depth == 0:
            key = k
         for i,j in walk_dict(v,depth+1,"recursive"):
             yield i, j
         print "bye"
      else:
         yield key, v
```

I have not tested the above code as I do not have the rest of the code to test it, but you can try it out.

Answer (score 0):

A rather basic suggestion. Are you sure that all the indentations are correct? This type of error situation regularly appears when tabs and spaces are mixed up.

You can't see it well in some editors unless you configure them to show the spacing visibly. I use Geany to edit Python code and have enabled the editor to show tabs and spaces, with the option 'Show white space'.

This is particularly confusing if you have programmed Tabs to be 4 characters. Python *always* considers a Tab 8 spaces, but possibly the editor shows it as 4.

Comment: I just double checked the tabbing. It is all correct. vim is showing four spaces as a tab, however, all the other code works fine so vim must only be displaying four of the eight spaces.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand that. If you just `cat` the program, does it appear correctly formatted?

Comment: Looking into it further based on the style recommendations of [PEP 0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) indentations should be four spaces and not eight. When I `cat` the program each indentation level is four spaces